# How to count overlapped values among columns

Tags: python, pandas, count, duplicates, overlap

Please let me ask a question about pandas dataframe.
For example, I have a dataframe like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dog': ['aa','bb','cc','dd','aa','ff'], 'Cat':['dd','ee','dd','as','ae','ee'], 'Bird':['ff','cd','ee','def','ae','as']})
df
```

Each column represents animal's information.
I want to know how many overlaps exist among animals.
For instance, Dog and Cat share "dd", so one overlap.
Dog and Bird share "ff", so one overlap.

Some animals have duplicates in their own columns.
For example, Dog has a duplicate as "aa".
So I want to remove the duplicates in an animal first and then want to analyze the number of duplicates among animals.

If you could give me your thoughts, I would be grateful for that very much.

P.S. Expected output is like this panel.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: Yes. I want a matrix dataframe.

Comment: If something were shared among three columns, how many overlaps would the be?

Comment: Harv Ipan is asking for the expected output, not a *description* of the output.

Comment: I do not know how to write the output but the expected output is like next comment.

Comment: Dog                         Cat                      Bird                                                                      Dog        6                            1                            1                                              Cat         1                            6                           3                                                                Bird        1                            3                           6

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. The main challenge is to get a crosstabulation of animals and features. After that, the co-occurrence matrix is obtained with matrix multiplication.

Note that the numbers on the diagonal reflect the number of unique features of each animal, which is different from your example.

```
# get rid of duplicates and align animal names with features
df2 = df.stack().reset_index(1).drop_duplicates()
# get a crosstabulation
df3 = pd.crosstab(df2.iloc[:, 1], df2.iloc[:, 0])
# coocurrence matrix is obtained with matrix multiplication
res = df3.T @ df3
# level_1  Bird  Cat  Dog
# level_1
# Bird        6    3    1
# Cat         3    4    1
# Dog         1    1    5
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'DataFrame' and 'DataFrame'

Comment: What is your `pandas` version? It works on pandas `0.23.0`; in any event, you can fall back on matrix multiplication with `res = pd.DataFrame(df3.values @ df3.T.values, index=df3.index, columns=df3.index)`